# How to simulate a lump of dirt washed away(dirt integration by fluid force) by running fluid in a pipe?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I am studying particle and fluid system of Blender to achieve an effect simulating dirt being washed away(dirt integration by fluid force) by running water in a pipe. I need tips or ideas of what the workflow in Blender should be for making this realistic.

What my thought is to make two simulation and combine them in timeline. First is this particles blown away by wind force, and second is of cause the water running. But it is hard to make this idea realistic since the two sims are not interactive. I fumble around many tutorials, but couldn't find a feasible way.

Thanks!

Comment: This may also be interesting: https://blenderartists.org/t/taichi-elements-mpm-solver-for-blender/1351110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic setup and workflow that I did to achieve the following results was:

1. Setup particle system and collision objects
2. Tweak settings until a somewhat realistic result is achieved.

This result I arrived at can be enough to pass as "realistic" because it has some collisions, Newtonian physics calculations and a rigid body simulation all happening at the same time.

The answer to your question depends a lot on how much realism you want. For example, I am using just the basic Newtonian particle system and not the fluid engine of the particle system or the more advanced Mantaflow engine in the Physics tab which can simulate very realistic fluid simulations.

The tip I would give you is to make simple things first and then build up to more complex things. Even the simple setups have many variables for you to work with and achieve different levels of real or fictional effects.

[image: dirt-push-out]

Comment: Thanks for contribution ... you could coloured the "lump of dirt" ... I haven't seen it for a few cycles :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a much better idea than doing the actual fluid simulation.